# Question regarding refraction of light through a spherical lens

Tags: optics, geometric-optics, lenses

I know that the divergence of a light ray through a biconcave lens can be explained through successive refractions inside the lens, somewhat like what is shown in the diagram (where the pink line and red lines represent the normals at the respective points).

[image: Refraction inside a biconcave lens]

But, the question is, what would happen if a ray is entering from **exactly** the vertex of the biconcave lens, making an angle $\theta$ with an imaginary line parallel to the principal axis, as shown (please pardon the bad annotation, the lines are meant to be straight):

[image: Refraction through the vertex of a biconcave lens]

At the vertex, a normal cannot be drawn. So, what would be the path of the light ray *inside* the lens (i.e. after refraction from the lens surface at $1$) in this case, and what would be the path of the emergent ray? Also, what would be the effect of change in angle $\theta$ on the path of light (up to a certain angle, as for very large $\theta$, the ray would not even go inside the lens)?

Comment: Classical geometric optics cannot answer how rays refract/reflect off an edge for that leads to diffraction.  One step closer to understand what happens you would need to employ Keller's (or Ufimtsev's) GTD ("Geometric Theory of Diffraction") or what is called PTD ("Physical Theory of Diffraction")  or some other analysis of scattering off a dielectric surface/edge.

Comment: @hyportnex Alright, but what do we experimentally **observe** when such a thing happens?

Comment: At the crudest level of approximation valid in the Fraunhofer zone every "paraxial geometrical optics" focused point in the image will have an "Airy disk" around it (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airy_disk). As the object gets closer to the lens the diffraction off the edges gets more and more complicated.